# How loop works in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: numItems * 2,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        if (i.isOdd) return const Divider();
        final index = i ~/ 2 + 1;
        return _buildRow(index);

//Explain each line fully
```

Comment: If numItems is 20 then how will it work

Answer (score 0):

```
return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: numItems * 2,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        if (i.isOdd) return const Divider();
        final index = i ~/ 2 + 1;
        return _buildRow(index);
          } 
       );
```

1. The property itemCount is to run this loop(builder) for numItems * 2 times i.e. suppose the value of numItems is 5 then it will build the widgets or the loop will run for 5*2=10 times.
2. The property padding will put the spacing around the whole list by 16 pixels, i.e. from left side of the screen your widget will be 16 pixels apart and simililary for other sides.
3. In itemBuilder here you have the body of the loop/builder and in this we have a condition if i is odd then divider will be shown on the phone screen else the value of index will become i~/2+1.

   For example, the value of 11 is 5 then index=11~/2+1

   index=5+1=6(~/ this operator will divide 11 by 2 and result is 5.5 and due to ~ it becomes 5)

   and after this you are returning the widget _buildRow() and passing the value of index to it.

   After this the value of i will be incremented and again point 3 will be repeated just like we have increment in other loops and again run the body of the loop.

Comment: then it will run 20 times and show divider widget 10 times and _buildRow also 10 times

Comment: Can you please show step by step working for numItems 20

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdWhYERuv7g have a look on this video to understand working